# GZipStream to gzip string

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzipstream

i´m using GZipStream to gzip string.
Can someone tell me if it is possible to control the level of compression? This is because I realize it is possible to create gzip streams more compressed than .net seems to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible in .NET 4.5 as a [new constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137341%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has been added which allows you to specify a compression level. Another possibility is to use a third party library that will allow you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You will get better compression using [#ZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

Comment: thanks for reply.as per my requirement i can not change from gzip to icsharp zip, but do you know how to change level of compression for Gzip ?